# imagefield(upload_to = 'myfolder') not save image in folder - 'myfolder' in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

form html:

```
<form action='/register/' method = 'post'>{% csrf_token %}
    ...
    <label>Avatar: </label><input type='file' name='avatar' value='' /><br />
    <input type = 'submit' name='submit' value='Sign up' />
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'avatar', blank = True, null = True)
    ...
```

and views.py

```
def register(request):
    success = False
    message = ''
    try:
        newE = Employee.objects.create(...
                                avatar = request.POST['avatar'])
        success = True
        message = 'Register successful!'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':str(success).lower(), 'message':message}))
    except:
        Employee.objects.filter(email = request.POST['email']).delete()
        message = 'Can\'t create a new account!'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':str(success).lower(), 'message':message}))
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/dotcloud/data/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

when I use the django admin page, the image will load and save:
http://training-hongquan156.dotcloud.com/media/**avatar**/image.png
but when I use html form upload photos, the image is not uploaded and saved in the folder '***avatar***', but saves the path:
http://training-hongquan156.dotcloud.com/media/image.png
and i can't load image...
what's problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should correct

```
<form action="/register/" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

handle the uploaded file with

```
request.FILES['avatar']
```

then find it in dir `$upload_to`,`/home/dotcloud/data/media/photo`